# "Notice period at your job" or "notice period on your job"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which preposition it is more natural to use after *notice period*: *at* or *on*? For example:

> Person A: How long is the notice period **at**/**on** your job?
>
> Person B: The notice period **on**/**at** my job is two weeks.

Comment: I'd say **for**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, you '*serve notice on*' someone, but the term is so common that most people use it less formally. Most people would say they 'gave notice *to*' their employer.

You don't appear to be talking about serving, or giving notice - just attributing the required notice period to a job role. For this, you should use the preposition '*for*', to show that the notice period belongs to, or is related to the job:

> How long is the notice period *for* your job?